# Dockerexecutable file not found in $PATH: unknown

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, jenkins-pipeline

I have a docker container, and I am trying to run a maven command on it. The docker container hosts a java app (springboot) on a working directory, so I do this command.

```
docker run -w $SERVICE_DIR --name 1234 --rm -v $SERVICE_DIR:$SERVICE_DIR $IMAGE "mvn package"
```

(Keep in mind, the environmental variables `$SERVICE_DIR` and `$IMAGE` are set and valid)

and I get the error :

```
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "mvn package": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.
```

I then try more basic commands, such as `mvn --version` or even `echo hi` and I get the same error.

However, when I do the ls command or pwd command like this:

```
docker run --name 1234 --rm -v $SERVICE_DIR:$SERVICE_DIR $IMAGE "ls"
```

there are no problems, command runs! I did some googling, and I think I did the order of my commands correctly... Also, I cannot do `/bin/bash` and run this interactively; I will be running this through a shell script.

Thanks

Comment: If you are sure that maven executable is present within the Docker base image you use, then try to remove the double quotes around your command otherwise the whole command would be interpreted as the name of the executable

Comment: Without Docker, you'd probably get a similar error running `"mvn package"` with double quotes (it forces the shell to consider the whole command as a single word) and in both cases you need to remove the quotes so it's two words.

Comment: Yup! TYSM, that seems to work. Previously I had the quotes because I was trying something like "pwd && whoami" (so 2 commands), but now that I only need 1 command, we are good.